# AssimpNet Exports Mesh without UV or Color Data

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am working on a wpf Net8 app that has a custom mesh class that I am trying to export to fbx using AssimpNet library but the exported mesh doesn't have any UV coordinates -only all vertices has vector3.Zero -
Neither any color data

My Mesh Creating Method

```
    private static Mesh CreateMesh(MeshNodeViewModel meshmodel, List<Bone> bones)
{
    var mesh = new Mesh(meshmodel.Name, PrimitiveType.Triangle);
    mesh.MaterialIndex = meshmodel.Mesh.MaterialIndex;

    for (int vi = 0; vi < meshmodel.Mesh.Vertices.Count; vi++)
    {
        var vertex = meshmodel.Mesh.Vertices[vi];
        mesh.Vertices.Add(vertex.Position.ToAssimp3());
        mesh.Normals.Add(vertex.Normal.ToAssimp3());
        mesh.Tangents.Add(vertex.Tangents[0].ToAssimp3());
        mesh.BiTangents.Add(vertex.Bitangent.ToAssimp3());
        for (var i = 0; i < vertex.Colors.Count; i++)
        {
            mesh.VertexColorChannels[i].Add(new Color4D(vertex.Colors[i].R, vertex.Colors[i].G,
                vertex.Colors[i].B, vertex.Colors[i].A));
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < vertex.UVs.Count; i++)
        { 
            // Extract UV information from the vertex for the current Layout 
            mesh.TextureCoordinateChannels[i].Add(vertex.UVs[i].ToAssimp3());

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vertex.BoneWeights.Length; i++)
        {
            // Extract bone information from the vertex
            string boneName = vertex.VertexBones[i];
            float boneWeight = vertex.BoneWeights[i];
            Bone existingBone = mesh.Bones.Find(b => b.Name == boneName);

            // If the bone doesn't exist, create a new one
            if (existingBone == null)
            {
                existingBone = new Bone { Name = boneName };
                mesh.Bones.Add(existingBone);
            }

            // Add the vertex weight to the bone
            existingBone.VertexWeights.Add(new VertexWeight
            {
                VertexID = vi,
                Weight = boneWeight
            });
        }

    }
    foreach (Bone bone in bones)
    {
        if (!mesh.Bones.Any(b => b.Name == bone.Name))
        {
            mesh.Bones.Add(bone);
        }
    }
    List<int> indices = new(meshmodel.Mesh.Vertices.Count);
    indices.AddRange(meshmodel.Mesh.FaceSets[0].Indices);
    indices.FlipFaceIndcies();

    for (var i = 0; i < indices.Count; i += 3)
    {
        var triangle = new int[3]
        {
                indices[i],
                indices[i + 1],
                indices[i + 2]
        };
        mesh.Faces.Add(new Face(triangle));
    }

    return mesh;
}
```

but i get how many layers coorectly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqmaX.png)

my Classes

```
      public class MyMesh : NodeModel
  {
    
      private int _materialIndex;

      public int MaterialIndex
      {
          get => _materialIndex;
          set => SetProperty(ref _materialIndex, value);
      }

      private string _materialName;

      public string MaterialName
      {
          get => _materialName;
          set => SetProperty(ref _materialName, value);
      }

      private byte _dynamic;

      public byte Dynamic
      {
          get => _dynamic;
          set => SetProperty(ref _dynamic, value);
      }

      private string _defaultBone;

      public string DefaultBone
      {
          get => _defaultBone;
          set => SetProperty(ref _defaultBone, value);
      }

      private int _defaultBoneIndex;

      public int DefaultBoneIndex
      {
          get => _defaultBoneIndex;
          set => SetProperty(ref _defaultBoneIndex, value);
      }

      private List<int> _boneIndices;

      public List<int> BoneIndices
      {
          get => _boneIndices;
          set => SetProperty(ref _boneIndices, value);
      }

      private List<MyVertex> _vertices;

      public List<MyVertex> Vertices
      {
          get => _vertices;
          set => SetProperty(ref _vertices, value);
      }

      private List<MyFaceSet> _faceSets;

      public List<MyFaceSet> FaceSets
      {
          get => _faceSets;
          set
          {
              if (SetProperty(ref _faceSets, value))
              {
                  foreach (var faceSet in _faceSets)
                  {
                      faceSet.PropertyChanged += OnFaceSetPropertyChanged;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

 public class MyVertex : IDisposable
   {
      public Vector3 Position;
      public MyVertexBones VertexBones;
      public VertexBoneIndices BoneIndices;
      public VertexBoneWeights BoneWeights;
      public Vector3 Normal;
      public int NormalW;
      public List<Vector3> UVs;
      public List<Vector4> Tangents;
      public Vector4 Bitangent;
      public List<VertexColor> Colors;
      private bool disposedValue;

      public MyVertex(int uvCapacity = 0, int tangentCapacity = 0, int colorCapacity = 0)
      {
          UVs = new List<Vector3>(uvCapacity);
          Tangents = new List<Vector4>(tangentCapacity);
          Colors = new List<VertexColor>(colorCapacity);
      }

      public MyVertex(MyVertex clone)
      {
          Position = clone.Position;
          BoneWeights = clone.BoneWeights;
          BoneIndices = clone.BoneIndices;
          Normal = clone.Normal;
          UVs = new List<Vector3>(clone.UVs);
          Tangents = new List<Vector4>(clone.Tangents);
          Bitangent = clone.Bitangent;
          Colors = new List<VertexColor>(clone.Colors);
      }
   }
```

Assimp Mesh

```
    namespace Assimp;

//
// Summary:
//     A mesh represents geometry with a single material.
public sealed class Mesh : IMarshalable<Mesh, AiMesh>
{
    private string m_name;

    private PrimitiveType m_primitiveType;

    private int m_materialIndex;

    private List<Vector3D> m_vertices;

    private List<Vector3D> m_normals;

    private List<Vector3D> m_tangents;

    private List<Vector3D> m_bitangents;

    private List<Face> m_faces;

    private List<Color4D>[] m_colors;

    private List<Vector3D>[] m_texCoords;

    private int[] m_texComponentCount;

    private List<Bone> m_bones;

    private List<MeshAnimationAttachment> m_meshAttachments;

    private MeshMorphingMethod m_morphMethod;

    private BoundingBox m_boundingBox;
       public Mesh(string name, PrimitiveType primType)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_primitiveType = primType;
        m_materialIndex = 0;
        m_morphMethod = MeshMorphingMethod.None;
        m_vertices = new List<Vector3D>();
        m_normals = new List<Vector3D>();
        m_tangents = new List<Vector3D>();
        m_bitangents = new List<Vector3D>();
        m_colors = new List<Color4D>[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_colors.Length; i++)
        {
            m_colors[i] = new List<Color4D>();
        }

        m_texCoords = new List<Vector3D>[8];
        for (int j = 0; j < m_texCoords.Length; j++)
        {
            m_texCoords[j] = new List<Vector3D>();
        }

        m_texComponentCount = new int[8];
        m_bones = new List<Bone>();
        m_faces = new List<Face>();
        m_meshAttachments = new List<MeshAnimationAttachment>();
    }


}
```